# Finding longest numeric subsequence inside a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string like:
"Aggecvehtafv12357748615ahfwgbej134"
I want to find the longest numeric subsequence inside that string in python. Answer to this I want is:
"12357748615"

Comment: OK, and which specific problem did you encounter while trying to solve this?

Comment: If you don't care about performance, you can use regex to match all numbers (`(\d+)`) and then find max by string len.

Answer (score 4):

Short solution: use `re.findall` to find the sequences of digits, and get the longest by using `len` as the key for `max`:

```
import re

s = 'Aggecvehtafv12357748615ahfwgbej134'

print(max(re.findall(r'\d+', s), key=len))
# '12357748615'
```

Comment: I tried this against an iterative approach and it is much faster than iterating through finding values and max length at the same time. (i.e. loop through i=0:len(s) and each break of digit check for maxLen) I imagine those functions are optimized through c for speed and will beat any pure python approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```py
def longest_number(input_string):
  '''
  input
  -----
  Provide the string

  Notes
  -----
  Takes the input string and returns the longest sequence of number inside 
  the string

  '''

  import re
  x = re.findall("\d+", input_string)
  len_ = [len(seq) for seq in x]
  idx = np.argmax(len_)
  return x[idx]
```